# Buscar registro por value de input y retornar el id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, blade, livewire

Estoy buscando la forma de traer el id de un registro y pasarlo a un textbox, esta busqueda es en base a un dni de otro input, tengo este codigo, pero me perdi en como realizar dicha busqueda.

```
public function callIdCustomer($dni)
    {
        $customerid = Customer::findOrFail($dni);
        $this->order->id_customer_id = $customerid;
    }
```

lo que busco es que la funcion me traiga el id donde el rutciente, es decir el input wire:model="rucliente" sea igual al registro campo dni en mi tabla...

la busqueda seria utilizando este input llamado rutcliente

```
<input class="mt-1 rounded-md" type="text" name="rutcliente" id="rutcliente" required wire:model.defer="rutcliente">
```

y necesito que al devolverme un resultado me cargue el id en este input

```
<div class="col-span-3 sm:col-span-3">
   <input type="number" wire:model="order.id_customer_id">
</div>
```

todo esto se ejecutara con un boton desde la plantilla blade.php

```
<button class="btn btn-indigo mr-2 mt-10" 
                    wire:click.debounce.400ms="createCustomer"
                    wire:click.debounce.1000.ms="callIdCustomer"
                    wire:click.prevent
                    >
                    Guardar cliente
            </button>
```

Comment: he editado a ver si se entiende mas! gracias

Comment: Creo que `findOrFail()` es para buscar solo por ID. En todo caso, deberías leer el registro con `$customer = Customer::where('columna_dni', $dni)->get();` y acceder al resultado para devolver ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo he solucionado de esta forma

```
public function callIdCustomer(Request $rutcliente)
{
    $rutcliente = $this->rutcliente;
    $customer = Customer::Select('id', 'dni')->where('dni', $rutcliente)->first(); 
    $this->order->id_customer_id = $customer->id;
    //dd($customer->id);        
}
```